# Angular/rxjs6 - GET before PUT

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would GET fresh data from DB before I PUT (edit) some record.

Service:

```
getVotes(): Observable<Vote> {
  return this._http.get<Vote>(url);
}

putVote(choose: string){
 this.getVotes().subscribe(
  result => {
    ...
    return this._http.put<Vote>(url + object).subscribe();
  }
 )
}
```

Now it's working but I think `putVote()` should return `Observable<Vote>` so how to return in from internal `getVotes()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map the response from `getVote()` using `switchMap` and Remove subscribe from `http.put()` to return Observable from `putVote()`

```
putVote(choose: string){
 return this.getVotes().pipe(switchMap(
  result => {
    ...
    return this._http.put<Vote>(url + object);
  }
 ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code?

```
getVotes(): Observable<Vote> {
  return this._http.get<Vote>(url);
}

putVote(choose: string): Observable<Vote> {
 this.getVotes().subscribe(
  result => {
    ...
    return this._http.put<Vote>(url + object).subscribe();
  }
 )
}
```